Get all places in a specific Polygon boundary
Using Google Places API, is it possible to extract all places within a specific polygon boundary? I just need the data, so I can populate our DB with all the places on that boundary.

You may be able to use the new Places Insights API to find places in specific regions. Note that this API will provide only Place IDs, so then you would need to fetch additional data using Place Details.
However, copying all data into your DB is not allowed by the Google Maps Platform Terms of Service, see also the Places API section in the Service Specific Terms. Besides, such data is changing all the time.
